# How to save images to sqlite database

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my classe I have a method that searches the image in the photo gallery and also receives the image taken from the camera of the mobile phone, I need now to save this image in the sqlite database. I am using a database field like BLOB, but not like serializing the image in bity [] or transforming in decode64 to write to the database.

I would like to know if anyone has any examples to pass on xaramin android I am posting the method that receives the image

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Make it available in the gallery
            try
            {
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(App._file);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
                SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display.
                // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory
                // and cause the application to crash.

                int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
                int width = imageView.Height;
                App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
                if (App.bitmap != null)
                {
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);
                    App.bitmap = null;

                }

                // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
                GC.Collect();
            }
            catch
            {


            }
            try
            {
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    var imageView =
                        FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
                        imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);

                }
            }
            catch {

            }

        }
```

Comment: What did you try to save the item in the database?